# Tkinter show grid on canvas

Tags: loops, tkinter, canvas

I would like to show/hide a grid on a `tkinter` canvas, as seen in Gimp for instance.

I have this code:

```py
is_on = True

def my_grid():
    global is_on
    global hor
    global ver
        
    if is_on:
        y=0
        x=0
        for i in range(8):
            x+=64
            y+=64
            hor=A.create_line(0,y,512,y, fill="black")
            ver=A.create_line(x,0, x, 512, fill="black")
        is_on=False
    else:
        A.delete(hor)
        A.delete(ver)
        is_on=True
```

This delete only the last row and the last column. I've also tried to loop the delete action but it doesn't work.

Hope someone could help me.

Best

Comment: You need to put all of the lines in a list instead of 2 variables. Think about it, you have 16 lines that you are trying to store in 2 variables: `hor` and `ver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a tag to the lines, you can manipulate all of the lines with a single statement.

Also, there's no need to delete and recreate the lines each time. You can hide the grid by setting their `state` to `"hidden"`.

For example, here's how to create, hide, and show the grid:

```py
def create_grid():
    x = y = 0
    for i in range(8):
        x+=64
        y+=64
        A.create_line(0,y,512,y, fill="black", tags=("grid",))
        A.create_line(x,0, x, 512, fill="black", tags=("grid",))

def show_grid():
    A.itemconfigure("grid", state="normal")

def hide_grid():
    A.itemconfigure("grid", state="hidden")
```

Comment: @TheLizzard: what's the purpose of you editing the answer just to change the way the code is marked up. What problem did that solve?

Comment: @TheLizzard: Thanks. I've edited your code in order to create the toggle button I was trying to code. The tags and the state attributes were something I wasn't really aware of. Very useful indeed.

Comment: @BryanOakley I thought that it looked better with syntax highlighting. Next time should I avoid adding syntax highlighting on your answers? I assumed that you wouldn't mind the edit

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class CanvasGrid(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.lines = []
        self.lines_displayed = False

    def display_lines(self):
        # If the lines are already displayed don't do anything
        if self.lines_displayed:
            return None
        self.lines_displayed = True
        # Clear the list of the lines as they are no longer on the screen
        self.lines.clear()

        # Get the width and height of the canvas
        width = super().winfo_reqwidth()
        height = super().winfo_reqheight()

        # Loop through and create the vertical lines
        for x in range(0, width-width//8, width//8):
            line = super().create_line(x, 0, x, height, fill="black")
            self.lines.append(line)

        # Loop through and create the horizontal lines
        for y in range(0, height-height//8, height//8):
            line = super().create_line(0, y, width, y, fill="black")
            self.lines.append(line)

    def hide_lines(self):
        # For each line that is on the screen
        for line in self.lines:
            # Delete the line
            super().delete(line)
        self.lines_displayed = False


# Example code that uses the class

def toggle_lines(event):
    if canvas.lines_displayed:
        canvas.hide_lines()
    else:
        canvas.display_lines()

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = CanvasGrid(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

canvas.display_lines()
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", toggle_lines)

root.mainloop()
```

I created an extension to the `tkinter.Canvas` class by adding `display_lines` and `hide_lines`. You can use the class as if you are using `tkinter.Canvas` but it has those 2 methods. To try out the example code click on the canvas to show/hide the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button

vertical = 8
horizontal = 8
canvas_width = 700
canvas_height = 500
grid_lst = []


def grid(mode):
    if mode == 'show':
        if len(grid_lst):
            return
        for hor in range(horizontal):
            y = (hor + 1) * (canvas_height / (horizontal + 1))
            grid_lst.append(canvas.create_line((0, y, canvas_width, y), fill='black'))
        for ver in range(vertical):
            x = (ver + 1) * (canvas_width / (vertical + 1))
            grid_lst.append(canvas.create_line((x, 0, x, canvas_height), fill='black'))
    if mode == 'hide':
        for line in grid_lst:
            canvas.delete(line)
        grid_lst.clear()


root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, bg='grey')
canvas.pack()

Button(root, text='Show Grid', command=lambda: grid('show')).pack(side='left', fill='x', expand=True)
Button(root, text='Hide Grid', command=lambda: grid('hide')).pack(side='right', fill='x', expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

This method uses just one function that has an argument which determines what to do with grid: either show or hide. It also uses variables in a way that changing them would also auto-adjust the grid: `vertical`, `horizontal`, `canvas_width`, `canvas_height`. And they do what they say. `vertical` determines the amount of vertical lines and `horizontal` determines the amount of horizontal lines so this is pretty adjustable and "dynamic".

EDIT: improved performance so that lines don't add up to the list if the `grid('show')` is called multiple times and so that the list gets cleared when `grid('hide')` is called.